# Is it allowed to use decltype on std::declval<T> (the function itself, not the result of calling it)?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

The following code triggers a static assertion on libstdc++:

```
#include <utility>

using t = decltype(std::declval<const void>);
```

Should it?

---

Motivation for this question:

The following `declval` implementation [proposed by Eric Niebler](https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=27798) (which is apparently a compile time optimization)

```
template<typename _Tp, typename _Up = _Tp&&>
_Up __declval(int);

template<typename _Tp>
_Tp __declval(long);

template<typename _Tp>
auto declval() noexcept -> decltype(__declval<_Tp>(0));
```

would be questionable if a user could legally observe the type of `std::declval<const void>`. The signature in the standard

```
template <class T>
add_rvalue_reference_t<T> declval() noexcept;
```

results in the type `const void ()` (or `const void () noexcept` in C++17), whereas the proposed version results in the type `void ()` (or `void () noexcept`).

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, the reason for the question seems pretty clear from the question itself...

Comment: Given that you're the one asking this question, I have zero confidence in my answer. But throwing it out there anyway. Is the `long` overload in Niebler's proposal just to handle cv-`void`?

Comment: @Barry, Unless there's another type that doesn't take well to having a reference applied to it, yes.

Comment: Where can I find information on how Eric's proposal works?

Comment: @ClaasBontus, It's similar to a common SFINAE technique that uses `decltype` in the return type to figure out whether an expression is valid. Here, there's no need to check an expression, only that `&&` can be applied to the type. Note that this was further simplified to remove `_Up` and use `_Tp&&` as the return type. If `_Tp&&` is a valid type, both overloads will take part in overload resolution and `int` wins over `long`. If it's not a valid type, only the second overload will be there. For more information, your best bet might be to look for expression SFINAE examples.

Answer (score 7):

[declval] stipulates that:

> If this function is odr-used (3.2), the program is ill-formed.

That's basically it. Where functions are concerned, odr-use means, from [basic.def.odr]:

> A function whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is odr-used
>   if it is the unique lookup result or the selected member of a set of overloaded functions (3.4, 13.3, 13.4),
>   unless it is a pure virtual function and either its name is not explicitly qualified or the expression forms
>   a pointer to member (5.3.1).

But also:

> An expression is *potentially evaluated* unless it is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5) or a subexpression
>   thereof.

And [dcl.type.simple]:

> The operand of the `decltype` specifier is an unevaluated operand (Clause 5).

So in `decltype(std::declval<const void>)`, `std::declval` isn't potentially evaluated and hence it's not odr-used. Since that's the one criteria on `declval` for the program to be ill-formed and we don't meet it, I think libstdc++ is wrong to emit the static assertion.

---

Though I don't think this is a libstc++ thing. I think it's more of a question of when `static_assert`s get triggered. The libstdc++ implementation of `declval` is:

```
template<typename _Tp> 
struct __declval_protector
{    
    static const bool __stop = false;
    static typename add_rvalue_reference<_Tp>::type __delegate();
};   

template<typename _Tp> 
inline typename add_rvalue_reference<_Tp>::type
declval() noexcept
{    
    static_assert(__declval_protector<_Tp>::__stop,
         "declval() must not be used!");
    return __declval_protector<_Tp>::__delegate();
}
```

Both gcc and clang trigger that `static_assert` in this context (but obviously not with `decltype(std::declval<const void>())`, even though we're in an unevaluated context in both cases. I suspect that's a bug, but it may simply be underspecified in the standard what the correct behavior is with regards to triggering `static_assert`s.

Comment: Hmm, I found a new one that doesn't trigger the static assert: `using t = decltype(static_cast<const void (*)()>(std::declval<const void>));`. I might ask a separate question w/r/t whether there's anything in the standard that says this cast is not required to work.

Comment: @T.C. I would've expected them to have equivalent validity so I am no help to you there. But I'm not even sure I'm right on this one.